# Unit testing in Databricks notebooks

Tags: github, pyspark, pytest, databricks, databricks-repos

The following code is intended to run unit tests in Databricks notebooks, using pytest.

```py
import pytest
import os
import sys

repo_name = "Databricks-Code-Repo"

# Get the path to this notebook, for example "/Workspace/Repos/{username}/{repo-name}".
notebook_path = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()

# Get the repo's root directory name.
repo_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(notebook_path))
    
# Prepare to run pytest from the repo.
os.chdir(f"/Workspace/{repo_root}/{repo_name}")
print(os.getcwd())
    
# Skip writing pyc files on a readonly filesystem.
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
    
# Run pytest.
retcode = pytest.main([".", "-v", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])
    
# Fail the cell execution if there are any test failures.
assert retcode == 0, "The pytest invocation failed. See the log for details."
```

This code snippet is in the [guide](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/testing.html#language-Python) provided by Databricks.
However, it produces the following error:

```bash
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Workspace//Repos/<email_address>/Databricks-Code-Repo/Databricks-Code-Repo'
```

This notebook is inside Databricks Repos. I have two other notebooks:

- `functions` (where I have defined three data transformation functions);
- `test_functions` (where I have defined test function for each of the data transformation functions from the previous notebook).

I get that the error has something to do with permissions, but I can't figure out what is causing it. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: most probably `pytest` is trying to write something to the WSFS representing Databricks Repo, maybe `__pycache__` files. But have you looked onto using Nutter to test notebooks directly? Like in this demo: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo

Comment: FWIW, I am facing the same issue and I can assure that I am not trying to write anything. I am merely trying to confirm that the path exists. I am pretty sure this used to work, though, so maybe Databricks changed some backend stuff that broke compatibility with `os.path`/`pathlib`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is silly, but I restarted the cluster and it worked.